# error building tensorflow with cuda support on windows with bazel

Tags: windows, bazel, tensorflow

I'm trying to compile TensorFlow with CUDA support on Windows 10 64bit via bazel.
This is how my system is set-up:

- Windows 10 64bit
- Nvidia GeForce 1050 with CUDA capabilities 6.1
- CUDA Toolkit v8.0 -> `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0`
- cuDNN v6.0 -> `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0`
- bazel 0.7.0 (renamed as bazel.exe) -> `C:\Users\eliam\bazel\0.7.0`
- MSYS2 64bit
- TensorFlow master branch -> `C:\Users\eliam\tensorflow`

I've also already set these environment variables:

```
BAZEL_PYTHON=C:/Users/eliam/Miniconda3
BAZEL_SH=C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe
BAZEL_VC=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC
BAZEL_VS=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
CUDA_PATH=C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0
CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/lib/x64
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/eliam/Miniconda3/python.exe
PYTHON_PATH=C:/Users/eliam/Miniconda3/python.exe
PYTHONPATH=C:/Users/eliam/Miniconda3/python.exe
PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/eliam/Miniconda3/lib/site-packages
PATH=C:\Users\eliam\bazel\0.7.0;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include;%PATH%
```

Bazel is set up with all the steps required by its website (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-windows.html)

MSYS2 is set up with all the steps required by its website (http://www.msys2.org/)

I manage to complete the configure.py without issues.

```
python ./configure.py
You have bazel 0.7.0 installed.
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [y/N]:
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GDR support? [y/N]:
No GDR support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N]:
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: y
CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 8.0]:


Please specify the cuDNN version you want to use. [Leave empty to default to cuDNN 6.0]:


Please specify the location where cuDNN 6 library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is C:/Program Files/NVIDIA                 GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0]:


Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size. [Default is: 3.5,5.2]


Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MPI support? [y/N]:
No MPI support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]:


Add "--config=mkl" to your bazel command to build with MKL support.
Please note that MKL on MacOS or windows is still not supported.
If you would like to use a local MKL instead of downloading, please set the environment variable "TF_MKL_ROOT" every time before build.
Configuration finished
```

After that I set some other environment variables with the following command:

```
set BUILD_OPTS='--cpu=x64_windows_msvc --host_cpu=x64_windows_msvc --copt=/w --verbose_failures --experimental_ui --config=cuda'
```

In order to prevent this error

```
$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --verbose_failures --subcommands //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
..............
WARNING: The lower priority option '-c opt' does not override the previous value '-c opt'.
____Loading package: tensorflow/cc
____Loading package: @local_config_cuda//crosstool
____Loading package: @local_config_xcode//
ERROR: No toolchain found for cpu 'x64_windows'. Valid cpus are: [
  k8,
  piii,
  arm,
  darwin,
  ppc,
].
____Elapsed time: 10.196s
```

Then I start bazel build, using the following command

```
bazel build -c opt $BUILD_OPTS //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

This is where the problems begin. This is a [link](https://pastebin.com/1W1iLvww) to the complete log.

Any idea why?

Comment: `--cpu=x64_windows_msvc` and `ERROR: No toolchain found for cpu 'x64_windows'` seem pretty self explanatory to me

Comment: That error has been solved with the `set BUILD_OPTS='--cpu=x64_windows_msvc --host_cpu=x64_windows_msvc --copt=/w --verbose_failures --experimental_ui --config=cuda`, as I said in my post.
The error I don't understand why is happening is the the last line of the post (there is a link to the whole log)

Comment: @talonmies could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the log is this:

```
ERROR: C:/msys64/home/eliam/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/BUILD:52:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/stream_executor:cuda_platform' failed (Exit 2).
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_platform.cc(48): error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_platform.cc(50): error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_platform.cc(52): error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found
Target //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer failed to build
```

[tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_platform.cc(48)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9b9cbbe2a69b7fcec72d82f271cb90839c3035b7/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_platform.cc#L48) has `strcmp` in it.

The compiler complains about `strcasecmp`, therefore something must be `#define`'ing `strcmp` to `strcasecmp`. Whatever the case, could you run the build with `--verbose_failures`? That'll show the command Bazel was executing. That may hint on what's happening.

Also, I see this in your envvars:

```
BAZEL_VC=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC
BAZEL_VS=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
```

You only need to set one of these. I recommend keeping `BAZEL_VC` since that points to a newer compiler. I admit I don't know what happens when both envvars are defined, whether Bazel prefers one to the other. But I do know it works fine with just one of them defined.